# Store - Show Total Amount Sold

Tags: expresso-store

We need to be able to show the total amount of items sold for a specific item.  How would we go about doing this?  So basically the amount that have sold in the past, this is more so for our own reporting reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for your own reporting then you can make use of the Reports section by navigating to Store > Reports and going to the Products Sold section. Enter in your custom date range (which can go back to the first purchase) and the items can be ordered by SKU. You can then view this report online or export it as a CSV or PDF which will contain the total number of products sold per SKU for a specified date range.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Is there anyway to code custom reports.  For instance we have 3 levels of "inception" haha.  We have a Collection that then has dates that then has 1-4 different items for that date.  For instance:  Clothing > November 1st> Design 1, Design 2, Design 3